# What is wrong with this php code? LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table for users ("usuarios") and a table for their friends ("AMIGOS"), what I wanna do is get the friends of an user id, i don't receive any error but i just can't see results...

```
<?php
  $host     = 'localhost';
  $username = 'root';
  $pwd      = '';
  $db       = "lyne";

  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$pwd,$db) or die('Unable to connect');
  if(mysqli_connect_error($con)) {
    echo "Failed to Connect to Database ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $id     = $_GET['prefID'];
  $sql    = "SELECT a.*, u.nome FROM AMIGOS a LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios u ON(u.USU_ID = a.usuario_dois) WHERE usuario_um ='$id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  if($result) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $data[]=$row;
    }
    print(json_encode($data));
  }      

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I just receive a blank screen (I'm just testing with GET, will be POST when done) Sorry for bad eng

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: Thx for this advice but this is only for my college, but if i have enough time i'll certainly fix that.

Comment: Just simply add `$id      = (int)$_GET['prefID'];` if the ID is numeric. But you really should be using prepared statements, not really any excuse.

Comment: That's true, i'll do that. Taking advantage you are answering me, let me ask you, im having a problem now, if you can help me i would be glad. I'll explain in another comment, just a sec.

Comment: 3 Tables (grupos, partgrupos, usuarios) i wanna pick 'usuario' 'ID' and select in 'partgrupos' where i have the same 'ID', then, show the 'grupos' 'nome' by 'grupo_id' found in 'partgrupos'

Example: SELECT a.*, u.nome FROM partgrupos a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios u ON(u.USU_ID = a.PARTICIPANTE_ID) WHERE PARTICIPANTE_ID ='1'

Comment: But i don't know how i suppose to search in 'grupos' for 'nome' (I'm new at that, sorry if is an easy thing :( )

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem is not the code. In my users list i have some people with accents in her names, like "André", and when the user is friend of one of these people, simply dont work, i dont really know why. That's it.

Comment: You probably have a problem with your encoding, check that you are using the same encoding everywhere (UTF-8 is the best option).

Comment: I'll do that, if i fix, i'll post here.